# Find inverse modulo using extended euclid's algorithm

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

```
inverse.modulo <- function(a, n){
```

GCD <- function(a, b){
    n = a
    m = b

```
while(m != 0){
  r <- n %% m
  n <- m
  m <- r
}
```

}
  while(n != 0){

}
  return(c(n, k))
}

Can you please help me with my code 
Thank you

Comment: Your code doesn't really relate to your question, and the c (n, k) at the end makes no sense. I think you should first clearly ask your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inverse Modulo  <- function(a,n) {

int i=n,v=0,d=1;

while(a>0) {

t=i/a;

x=a;

a=i%x;

i=x;

x=d;

d=v-t*x;

v=x;

}

v%=n;

if(v<0) v+=n;

return v;

}

this code is written in C# but its contain just the basics of any coding language so i think you can convert it to the coding language you are using.

Comment: Do you have an email?